Pytest - parametrizing a test method from a fixture
I have a scenario where there is a fixture (in conftest.py) that reads data from a file and returns a dict. I have to use this dict to parametrize a test method. Can someone help me with this?
The problem is I couldn't pass the fixture directly in the parametrize

can you please include some code of what you are trying to do?

I can explain it
I have fixture that reads a .yaml file and returns the data (which is a nested dict)
I need to use each and every dict from the fixture to parametrise my test method using @pytest.mark.parametrize()

Does this answer your question? Pytest: How to parametrize a test with a list that is returned from a fixture?

Parametrize tries to get list parameters before fixture called so it doesn't work if you parametrize your tests using:
@pytest.mark.parametrize("name", list_name)

So, as a work around, you can change your approach by adding below lines to your conftest.py file.
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # read file and create your list/dict (lets assume you named it as: parametrize_list)
    if "parametrize" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("parametrize", parametrize_list)

then you all need to add parametrize to your test function as:
def test_example(parametrize):
    # your code


You can use better namings according to your situation.
